# OSM timestamp missing in SpatiaLite layer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, spatialite, timestamp

I have downloaded and converted a geofabrik pbf file to a db file.  When I open it as a SpatiaLite layer there is no timestamp for each feature.  Is there a way to get this information or is it lost in the conversion?

The timestamp is important for me to compare updates.

I have tried using the QuickOSM plugin but I need to work with large datasets and it is too slow.

Comment: How did you do the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used GDAL for conversion, read the driver manual https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html and find the `osmconf.ini` file from your GDAL_DATA directory. The keys which will be converted are selected with that configuration file. For most users the timestamps are waste of space and they are skipped by default. See the default settings in the osmconf.ini file

```
[points]
# common attributes
osm_id=yes
osm_version=no
osm_timestamp=no
```

There are separate settings for each layer (points, lines...).

Comment: That's what I used.  I can't locate the osmconf.ini file.  I'm on windows 10, any ideas?

Comment: If you used OSGeo4W installer it may be at `C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal` but you will find it by name with file explorer or from the command line `dir \s osmconf.ini`. Or check the value of the environmental variable with `set gdal_data`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked.  I see there are other edits I can make as well, this helps a lot.  Thank you.